# How to optimise a nested pattern match with multiple repeated cases?

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching

Please consider this code:

```
case action1 of
  Right a -> a
  Left (Failure1 a) -> a
  Left (Failure2 a) -> 
    case action2 a of
      Right a -> a
      _ -> error "Unexpected failure"
  _ -> error "Unexpected failure"
```

You can see that I have to repeat myself twice: with the `Right` and with the `error` cases.

How can I optimise this? Is it possible at all?

Comment: Your shadowed variable `a` isn't so nice, is it? I innocuously copied it at first, but it breaks my solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd put the error handling part outside the `case` part:

```
fromMaybe (error "Unexpected failure") $
    let eitherToMaybe = either (const Nothing) Just
    in case action1 of
          Right a           -> Just a
          Left (Failure1 a) -> Just a
          Left (Failure2 a) -> eitherToMaybe (action2 a)
          _                 -> Nothing
```

Comment: I have to say that from idiomatical standpoint this is a very nice solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

That's a good application for [pattern guards](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Pattern_guard):

```
case action1 of
  Right a -> a
  Left f
    | Failure1 a <- f       -> a
    | Failure2 a <- f
    , Right b <- action2 a  -> b
  _ -> error "Unexpected failure"
```